# Error: Does not name a type

Tags: c++, error

I have made a class called subjects and I have then made a subject called math. I am trying to set a classroom for math but it is giving me the error 'math' doesn't name a type.

Code for the class

```
class subject {
public:
  char subjectname[];
  char classroom[];

};
```

Code for the classroom and math

```
subject math;
math.classroom = "A1";
```

How can I set the classroom of math to A1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class subject {
public:
  char subjectname[];
  char classroom[];

};
```

This creates a class `subject` which has two `char` arrays of unspecified size as its members. This will attempt to create an array of size 0 (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722632/what-happens-if-i-define-a-0-size-array-in-c-c)). This is not what you want. You can e.g. statically allocate the space with a maximum number of characters beforehand and then `strncpy()` your new string inside the buffer.

This would look like

```
class subject {
public:
  char subjectname[32];  //32 bytes buffer
  char classroom[32];
};
```

And later

```
subject math;
strncpy(math.classroom, "A1", 31); //copy at max 31 bytes to not overwrite the NUL terminator
Serial.print("Classroom is: ");
Serial.println(math.classroom)
```

Or, just use the Arduino `String` class.  For example

```
#include <Arduino.h>
class subject {
public:
  String subjectname;
  String classroom;
};
```

Then your first usage code can be used unmodified.

Example

```
#include <Arduino.h>

class subject {
public:
  String subjectname;
  String classroom;
};

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);

    subject math;
    math.classroom = "A1";

    Serial.print("Classroom is: ");
    Serial.println(math.classroom);
}

void loop() { }
```

Comment: I tried using this code but it gives me the error 'math' does not name a type at the math.classroom line.

    `#include <Arduino.h>
    class subject {
    public:
         String subjectname;
         String classroom;
 
    };

    subject math;
    math.classroom = "A1";`

Comment: @TechnicProblem I can compile https://pastebin.com/5hVgtTi7 just fine. Does that compile for you?

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know I should've put some of the code in void setup(). Now it works.

Comment: @TechnicProblem You can put global variables outside of function scopes but not assignments and operations on them. Those must be in functions.

Comment: +1 for your excellent answer. FWIW, the String sketch's compile size is 3644 bytes, and the strncpy sketch is 2112 bytes. +100 for using a class in your sketch. The difference in compile size (using the strncpy sketch) VS the same strncpy sketch with all the added OOP code is 0 bytes. Using a class costs you nothing, and gives you a lot. It is unfortunate that there are 3 votes to close this question, stating it's off topic. According to this page: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic , "Specific questions about Arduino boards, code…" are "On Topic".